# Django: I get this error: " AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith' " when I try migrate in django

Tags: django, django-models, migration, attributeerror, django-migrations

I get this error: " AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith' " when I try migrate  in django

This is my code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
 
class MenuItem(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, db_index=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
 
 
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menuitem = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
 
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('menuitem', 'user')
  
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    delivery_crew = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='delivery_crew', null=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=False)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateField(db_column=True)
 
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menuitem = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('order', 'menuitem')
```

I have tried deleting the old migrations and running it again but it didn't work. I was able to make migrations successfully but I couldn't migrate

This is the error message I get

```
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Little_lemon_capstone\LittleLemon\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Little_lemon_capstone\LittleLemon\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\littlelemon-DilRqmD_\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\littlelemon-DilRqmD_\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute       
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\littlelemon-DilRqmD_\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv     
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\littlelemon-DilRqmD_\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\littlelemon-DilRqmD_\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\littlelemon-DilRqmD_\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 349, in handle    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\littlelemon-DilRqmD_\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\littlelemon-DilRqmD_\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\littlelemon-DilRqmD_\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration 
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\littlelemon-DilRqmD_\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 130, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\littlelemon-DilRqmD_\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 96, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\littlelemon-DilRqmD_\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 444, in create_model   
    sql, params = self.table_sql(model)
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\littlelemon-DilRqmD_\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 249, in table_sql      
    self.quote_name(field.column),
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\littlelemon-DilRqmD_\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 202, in quote_name     
    return self.connection.ops.quote_name(name)
  File "C:\Users\USER\.virtualenvs\littlelemon-DilRqmD_\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\operations.py", line 190, in quote_name
    if name.startswith('"') and name.endswith('"'):
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Comment: It seems that error is related to some migration file.

Comment: please share complete error trace

Comment: Thank for your reply @SunderamDubey what do suggest I do